# Overloading bitwise operators in Java

Tags: java, operators

I learnt that Java does not give provision to programmer to overload an operator.
I also learnt that `+` is the only operator overloaded in java,

But,

Operators `&` `|` `^` work on integral operands as bitwise operators.

Operators `&` `|` `^` work on boolean operands as logical operators.

My question:

1. Can I say that operators `&` `^` `|` are overloaded?
2. Is my jargon correct on calling these operators as bitwise operators on integral operands and logical operators on boolean operands?

Comment: Where did you read that `+` is the only overloaded operator? *All* the arithmetic ones are overloaded, to start with...

Comment: @shekharsuman: No, Java doesn't have *user-defined* operator overloading. Big difference.

Comment: @shekharsuman Java doesn't have **programmable** operator overloading. But the `+` operator is indeed overloaded.

Comment: @JonSkeet-I meant that only. Sorry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because we tend to view numbers as just numbers, we often don't recognise arithmetic operators to be overloaded, despite the obvious fact that an integer division is very different from a floating point division.

So technically all the arithmetic operators are very much overloaded.

The easiest way to determine what's overloaded is to imagine that instead of the + operator you had to call `Operators.plus()`. When that method needs to be overloaded to deal with different inputs, so will your operator.

So for example when you use `+` in a string concatenation sense, that would be equivalent to `Operators.plus(Object first, Object second)`, whereas an integer addition would be covered by `Operators.plus(int first, int second)`, and so on.

*(However, as a thought-experiment, if we take  the "relaxed" (and incorrect) view that all numbers are just numbers, we can then say the bitwise operators behave identically for all ordinal types, provided that we regard `boolean` as a number that is one bit long.)*

P.s.: The only important thing to remember (from a practical point of view) is that `|` and `&` with `boolean` operators **don't** short-circuit, while `||` and `&&` do. I personally wouldn't overly worry about terminology too much so long as people understand what you mean. As you can't overload operators in Java (as a user) anyway, it's less critical than in languages where you can.

Comment: `boolean` type is not integral type in java unlike C.

Comment: am not getting an undestanding of, when to call an operator as overloaded. that is my first question. BTW, I did not -1.

Comment: @overexchange I didn't say it was.

Comment: @overexchange That's simple: when the code implementing the operator is different. Imagine that instead of the `+` operator you had to call `Operators.plus()`. When that method needs to be overloaded to deal with different inputs, so will your operator.

Comment: Actually, we would need an entire zoo of overloaded `plus` methods, to model all the existing combinations, or assume a behavior as-if autoboxing happens, but even then, we have `(String,Object)` and `(Object,String)` (but not `(Object,Object)`)…